# Update blob in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blob

I can't figure out what is wrong with my SQL. Here is the PHP script that generates the query:

```
function SaveData($data,$id,$file)
{
    $handle = fopen($file['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $datafile = fread($handle, filesize($file['file']['tmp_name']));
    $datafile = mysql_real_escape_string($datafile);
    fclose($handle);        
    $query= "UPDATE data SET Text='" . $data['Text'] . "', Binary='$datafile', Tag='" . $data['Tag'] . "', name='" . $file['file']['name'] . "',type='" . $file['file']['type'] . "', size='" . $file['file']['size'] . "' WHERE Object_ID=".$id;

    mysql_query($query,$this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   'Binary='%PDF-1.5\r%âãÏÓ\r\n37 0
>   obj\r<

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`BINARY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL.

You need to use backticks or change the column name.

```
`Binary` = '$datafile'
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary is the reserved word

Try to enclose it in back quotes

```
`Binary`='$datafile',
```

Here is the list of keywords [Mysql Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax error pointed out by the other answers, you can't just shove a variable with binary data into an SQL query like that. You'll have to convert it to a hex string first.

```
function SaveData($data,$id,$file)
{
    $handle = fopen($file['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb'); // note the b here
    $datafile = fread($handle, filesize($file['file']['tmp_name']));
    $contents = bin2hex(($datafile)); // no need to escape this
    fclose($handle);        
    $query= "UPDATE data SET Text='" . $data['Text'] . "', `Binary`=x'$contents'; 
    // rest of the code trimmed
}
```

Also note that your field must be a `BLOB` to accept binary data.